# Use helper in plugin-controller CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, helper

I've baked a Plugin. The Controller in the Plugin works fine. Within the Controller I want to use the HtmlHelper within the Controller.

But... the Controller is complaining: `$this->Html` stays `null`.

The Controller in the Plugin contains: `public $helpers = array('Html');`
For debug purposes I have changed the location to $helpers to the `AppController`.
In the folder Controller I've added a `TestsController` which extends from `AppController`. He has a working HtmlHelper.

My Plugin Controller extends also from the `AppController`:

Plugin Controllers:
- UserManagerAppController extends from AppController
- UsercomponentsController extends from UserManagerAppController

Normal Controller folder:
- AppController extends from Controller

Why doesn't UsercomponentsController contains a HtmlHelper?

Comment: "In the folder Controller I've added a TestsController which extends from AppController. He has a working HtmlHelper." How exactly did you manage this? Were you ever able to debug($this->Html) in a controller and get a non-null value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `public $helpers = array('Html');` will **not load the helper in your controller**, it will load it in the **view file** rendered by your controller. You will be able to use the $this->Html reference in the view rendered, not any controller action. This is regardless of whether you try to load the Helper in a plugin controller or a normal one.

Check the package tree in the [Cake Docs](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/package-Cake.View.html) and read more on the differences between a Component and a Helper. You can use a [Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html) in a Controller and a [Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html) in a View. You should not have the need to use the HtmlHelper (which assists with creating HTML form elements) in the controller. That would break the MVC paradigm.

Comment: Thanks, for helping. Yes, it was a misunderstanding. It's now clear to me.